# Why can't g++ find/link to qjpeg4.dll?

Tags: windows, qt, gcc, linker, mingw

Using Qt Creator 2.4.1 (Windows/mingw), I'm trying to compile my project dynamically linking with some Qt image plugins (i.e. the ones in `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\plugins\imageformats\`). In the .pro file:

`QTPLUGIN += qjpeg qgif qico qtiff`

This is the error:

`g++ -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\myproject.exe object_script.myproject.Release  -L"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain release\myproject_res.o -L. -lswscale-2 -lavcodec-54 -lavdevice-53 -lavfilter-2 -lavformat-54 -lavutil-51 -lusb -lPsapi -lasa047 -lsphinxbase -lpocketsphinx -LC:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\plugins/imageformats -lqjpeg -lqgif -lqico -lqtiff -lQtMultimedia4 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4`

`c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqjpeg`

In the above you can see `-LC:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\plugins/imageformats` specified before `-lqjpeg` and `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll` exists ... so what gives?

Additional info: I can comment out the `QTPLUGIN` line in the .pro file and put instead:

`LIBS += -LC:\\QtSDK\\Desktop\\Qt\\4.8.1\\mingw\\plugins\\imageformats -l:qjpeg4.dll`

This links successfully, but I'm more interested in why `QTPLUGIN` appears broken out of the box under Windows mingw. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a known (unresolved) bug with qmake: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24177?focusedCommentId=179693#comment-179693